# How to type telnet escape character in OS X terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

How does one type that? On Finnish/Swedish keyboard  <kbd>Alt-9</kbd> is `]`,
but <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-9</kbd> gives just `9`.

(For non-scandinavians, `[]` and `{}` are Alt-8/9 and Shift-Alt-8/9 respectively in SE/FI keyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I enabled the Finnish and Swedish keyboard layouts and experimented with *Terminal* on OS X 10.8.5 a bit…

- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>å</kbd> generated `^]` (U+001D)
  <kbd>å</kbd> (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE) is an unmodified key in these layouts.
  It is located where <kbd>[</kbd> (LEFT SQUARE BRACKET) is with US layouts.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>ä</kbd> generated `^[` (U+001B)
  <kbd>ä</kbd> (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS) is an unmodified key in these layouts.
  It is located where <kbd>'</kbd> (APOSTROPHE) is with US layouts.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> generated `^_` (U+001F)
  <kbd>-</kbd> (HYPEN-MINUS) is an unmodified key in these layouts.
  It is located where <kbd>/</kbd> (SOLIDUS, a.k.a. “forward slash”) is with US layouts.

As normal, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> generated `^@` (U+0000) and <kbd>Delete</kbd> generated `^?` (U+007F).

I did not find any combination that generated `^\` (U+001C) or `^^` (U+001E) in *Terminal* though. There may be other combinations that work in other terminal emulators though (e.g. *iTerm* 2 in its default configuration arranges for <kbd>Control</kbd> with <kbd>2</kbd>–<kbd>8</kbd> generate the “non-alphabetic” control characters; this is similar to how *xterm* works).

Comment: `^[` is the same as `ESC`, which can be generated more simply with the Escape key.

Answer (score 5):

You can run `telnet` with a different escape char using `telnet -e`.

For instance, to use <kbd>control A</kbd>, type `telnet -e ^A`.

You may also create a file `~/.telnetrc` with this contents:

```
DEFAULT
   set escape ^A
```

In both cases `^A` is `^` followed by `A`, not <kbd>control A</kbd> typed directly.

Comment: Any idea what those proper settings might be? (`No manual entry for telnetrc`)

Comment: `man telnet` says that it's the same as when using `telnet` in interactive mode: `set escape ^A`.

Comment: does not work for me...

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just type 'quit' then press 'Return' button.

Comment: You can't type `quit` until you enter the escape character.