# Escape character ^] not working from Mac terminal

Tags: command-line, macos

If I ssh into an Ubuntu machine from my Mac with a "UK extended" keyboard and run telnet localhost 4730 I see:

```
me@ip-10-xx-xxx-30:~$ telnet localhost 4730
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But `ctrl + ]` does not work from a terminal on Mountain Lion. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have?

Comment: @HugoBuff Mac UK extended

Comment: So I suppose this question is about changing the escape character?

Comment: @Seth maybe? I just want to be able to enter the escape character and can't

Comment: The point is, this is either a configuration option on your Mac OSX machine (which we don't support here) or you can change the default behavior of Ubuntu and change the escape character, which is supported here.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to change the default Ubuntu escape character or send ^] from the OSX terminal?

Comment: I'm on OSX and ctrl-] works fine.

Comment: I have a azerty keyboard (no ] at all on it, you have to press ⌥+⇧+) ), and pressing ^$ (where the ] key is on a qwerty keyboard) works for me.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but here is how I would narrow down the precise location of the problem, once you ssh into the ubuntu host, telnet to towel.blinkenlights.nl and test the escape sequence ⌃] on that host.

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106763/how-to-type-telnet-escape-character-in-os-x-terminal?rq=1 help?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if I hit <kbd>return</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> it works.